# Unity3D: UGUI Benefits of applying a Material to UI Image elements

Tags: unity-game-engine

The UI Image (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html) object has a Material and Source Image attribute.

Two Questions:

1. If I'm just rendering plain square solid-color element in my UI (ie a
   background or non-rounded button) is there any benefit to setting a
   non-null source image?  I thought maybe adding a white 'filler' sprite that's attached to a central sprite map might reduce draw calls or something, but it appears that it has no effect vs just leaving the sprite null.
2. In the same plain square solid-color element, is there any benefit to using non-null
   Material?  As in, are the default UI shaders provided by Unity any
   extra performance value over just using the null setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, use a white filler sprite that is in your sprite atlas so that the UI engine can easier batch those draw calls together. but don't expect too much of a performance boost from that, unless you have a lot of them.

2) Yes, I wrote two special super simple shaders: one for invisible images (used for hidden buttons) and one for opaque images. This dramatically improved the performance, in a test scenario with 12 overlapping opaque images on an iPad 3, from 26ms down to 4ms frame render time, which is an massive increase from 38 FPS to theoretical 250 FPS.

Comment: Can you reference anything that supports #1?  I've seen the 'filler' sprite used in various assets and whatnot but I can't in any real-world test ever verify it has any impact on batching.  No sense in doing that if the benefit can't be proven... smells like some old school techniques lingering in what might very well be unnecessary in Unity5.x.  Regarding #2, sounds sexy... I'll look into that.

Comment: yes to #1: if i have 11 sprites with no image and 1 sprite with an image in between. you can see in the frame debugger that it creates 3x "Draw Mesh", but if all images are in the same atlas it is just 1x "DrawMesh".